# Design pattern for different input parameter type and data extraction algorithm

Tags: generics, design-patterns, template-method-pattern

I am new to design pattern.

My question is what pattern do I use in below case?

```
interface UserExtractorService {
    String getUser(XXXX);
    default validate(File file);
}

class AExtractorService {
    public String getUser(String url) {
           validate(downloadfromWeb(url));
       return getFromWeb(url);
    }
}

class BExtractorService {
    public String getUser(File) {
           validate(file);
           parsingFromFile(File);
       return parsingFromFile(File);
    }
}

class Client {

    public void GetUsers(String key) {
         userExtractorService.getUser(key);
    }

    public void GetUsers(File file) {
         userExtractorService.getUser(file);
    }
}
```

I want to group AExtractor and BExtractor, because it need operate similar behavior.

Comment: Are classes implementing interface? but then getUser() methods are overloaded versions. Are both exposed in interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one takes a closer look at the user-case, it should be clear that there are two main aspects of the design that need to be flexible :

1. The parameter type of the `getUser` method can be `String` in one case and `File` in other cases.
2. The mechanism to extract the user data will vary depending on the source i.e, extract from a web url or a file

**Point 1** can be tackled by using generics/template functions where `UserExtractorService` can have a type parameter or the `getUser` method can have a type parameter. The type parameter of the class or function would represent the input parameter type for the `getUser` function and would be defined by the client while instantiating the `UserExtractorService` implementations.

**Point 2** can be tackled by using the [Template method design pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-template-method). Note that this is different from C++ template classes and methods. Template method pattern is a behavioral design pattern that defines the program skeleton of an algorithm in an operation, defering some steps to subclasses.

Translating this to code, the `getUser` method would be the template method. Next, one would define an abstract method called `String extractUserData(T source)` which would be called in `getUser`. This abstract method will be implemented by subclasses and would contain the algorithm for extracting data from a particular source. We would essentially have one subclass per source of user data (Web, File) etc. An example of the `getUser` method in *Java* would be as follows :

```
abstract class UserExtractorService<T> {
   public final String getUser(T source) {
         validate(source);
         return extractUserData(source);
   }

   protected abstract String extractUserData(T source);
   protected abstract void validate(File f);
}
```